# Processing arguments for subprocesses using argparse: "Expected one argument"

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

First of all, I am sorry about the title that does not give a perfect idea of what my problem is, I kinda struggled with it, so I am going to illustrate it more clearly with a reproducible example:

I have the following code:

**example.py:**

```
import argparse


def parse_args():
    """Command line argument parser

    Returns:
        The extra arguments
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Arguments for test runner")
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--extra_args', type=str, default="", help="Extra arguments. Enter as a single line encapsulated by quotes. Example: -e \"--repeat=0 otherstuff -x anotherpositional\"")

    arguments = parser.parse_args()

    return arguments


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    print(args.extra_args)
```

The `--extra_args` argument is then going to be used as a positional argument for a subprocess call.

The argument I need to pass is the following one: `--repeat=0`. It does not work, I got the following results:

```
python example.py -e "toto" # This print toto
python example.py -e "--repeat = 0" # This print --repeat = 0
python example.py -e "--repeat" # error: argument -e/--extra_args: expected one argument
python example.py -e "--repeat=0" # error: argument -e/--extra_args: expected one argument
```

What I understand is that the parser process the `--repeat` as an argument, find no value for it, and breaks. But unfortunately I have no choice than to write '--repeat=0' all attached, because of the software receiving it.

Would you know any workaround around it ?

Comment: The quotes tell `bash` to keep the string together, but they don't make a difference in what `argparse` sees and does.  `python example.py -e --repeat` is the same as your third example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ugly workaround but if it exit, I would enjoy a better solution.

I added the following function:

```
def __workaround_for_extra_utr_args():
    """This workaround is necessary because utr can receives args at \"--repeat=0\" which are not processable by arg parse, even as a string"""
    import sys

    index_of_extra_args = [sys.argv.index(v) for v in ['-e', '--extra_utr_args'] if v in sys.argv]
    space = " "

    if index_of_extra_args:
        index_of_extra_args = index_of_extra_args[0]

        if space not in sys.argv[index_of_extra_args + 1]:
            sys.argv[index_of_extra_args + 1] = sys.argv[index_of_extra_args + 1] + space
```

Call it before calling the parser, and it will be able to return the string, it is then possible to remove the extra space after the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with the way `parse_args` inteprets the double dash at the beginning of the arg string.

If you add a prefix, it could be a single character, like a space within the string, this could be a workaround.

```sh
python example.py -e " --repeat=0" # OK
python example.py -e ":--repeat=0" # OK
python example.py -e " --repeat=0 --foo=1 --boo=2" # OK
```

It would be easy then in your code to strip the extra_args of the first character or whatever prefix.

```py
import argparse


def parse_args():
    """Command line argument parser

    Returns:
        A tuple containing the toolset version and a force flag
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Arguments for test runner")
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--extra_args', type=str, default="", help="Extra arguments. Enter as a single line encapsulated by quotes. Example: -e \"--repeat=0 otherstuff -x anotherpositional\"")

    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    arguments.extra_args = arguments.extra_args[1:]

    return arguments


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    print(args.extra_args)
```

Not ideal but an easy workaround.

Comment: The thing is that I do not want the user to have to know about the workaround, it makes things more complex for them

Comment: I understand that and they should not especially as you would be exposing a bug workaround in the spec of your consumers. I would personally spec the extra arguments to be without dashes as in ` python example.py -e "repeat=0 foo=1 bar=2"`. This is totally acceptable to consumers, your code can easily add the dashes before passing the extra arguments to the subprocess. This might have a positive side effect of distinguishing main process args from subprocess args more clearly. Your inner programmer might be screaming feeling like a defeat but sometimes being pragmatic is the best choice.

Comment: I could be, except the subprocess does not respect any standard, some arguments have --, some have none. So I cannot take that as granted. I found a way to process the extra args by editing the sys.argv before the parsing, then processing back the argument to a correct value once parsed. So it's all good, no impact at all on the consummer

Answer (score 0):

Handling values that start with a '--' is a challenge with `argparse`.  The idea that it marks a flag (as with your `--extra_args`) is so integral to `argparse`, that it's hard to work around it.

Simply adding quotes doesn't help.  They control how the shell handles the strings, but doesn't otherwise change what's in `sys.argv`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing

describes the use of pseudo-argument "--", but that only works for positional arguments.  (I'd have to look at the code again to see why it doesn't do anything with optionals.)

So with:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Arguments for test runner")
parser.add_argument('extra_args', nargs='*')
arguments = parser.parse_known_args()
print(arguments)
```

I get:

```
919:~/mypy$ python3 stack72129874.py -- --repeat
argv ['stack72129874.py', '--', '--repeat']
(Namespace(extra_args=['--repeat']), [])

0919:~/mypy$ python3 stack72129874.py -- --repeat=0
argv ['stack72129874.py', '--', '--repeat=0']
(Namespace(extra_args=['--repeat=0']), [])

0920:~/mypy$ python3 stack72129874.py -- --repeat = 0
argv ['stack72129874.py', '--', '--repeat', '=', '0']
(Namespace(extra_args=['--repeat', '=', '0']), [])

0920:~/mypy$ python3 stack72129874.py -- "--repeat = 0"
argv ['stack72129874.py', '--', '--repeat = 0']
(Namespace(extra_args=['--repeat = 0']), [])
```

There is a `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` that works like the pseudo-argument, but again only for positionals.  And there are some problem with using it, so it's now undocumented.

Adding spaces such as in " --repeat = 0" has been mentioned in previous SO about the topic.

And if you don't really need the rest of the `argparse` machinery (help, error handling, other arguments), doing your own parsing of `sys.argv` is a perfectly find solution.